# How to detect if is the user the fan of my page

Tags: facebook

I have a little problem, I don't know how to create the script (with PHP SDK) which check if is the user a fan of my page.

I successfly get the permission for user_likes, but I cant post data to array and after check it.

When I dump this code: `$user_likes = $facebook->api('/me/likes');` I'll got all data, but I cant post them to array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's amazing what one can find on the internet these days if only he tries to Google his questions...

Here's the first result I got for "facebook is the user a fan":

http://www.masteringapi.com/tutorials/facebook-api-check-if-a-user-is-fan-of-a-facebook-page/20/

It discuss a few options, PHP and JavaScript, Graph API and REST API, just pick your favorite.

Answer (score 1):

```
FB.api("me/likes/270801249647033", function(response) {
    if ( response.data.length == 1 ) { 
        // Has liked
    } else {
        // Not liked
}});
```

[Source and download script](http://www.webtuts.info/webdevelopment/facebook-download-script-2/225/)

Answer (score 0):

From:  http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/pages.isFan/ (yes, this is deprecated, but it includes the new Graph API way to do things at the top of it.  :) )

You can now issue a HTTP GET request to `/USER_ID/likes/PAGE_ID` (aka `/me/likes/PAGE_ID` ) to check if a user is a page of a fan.

Comment: Any particular reason to use the old REST API?

Comment: why send him to a deprecated functionality instead of for what he needs: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#likes

Comment: No, just used the REST API documentation as the example that has the newer code in it.  I like the fact that you can directly go to that page id by specifying it on the URL

Comment: Please, don't use the old REST API.